# Hide InputEl extjs of datefield

Tags: extjs, datepicker, extjs4.2, datefield

i need to hide the inputEl of a ExtJS 4.2 datefield. I want to hide the input because i have to do a lot of modify of the page when the user select a date from the datepicker. 
Anyone know the fast method for do that?

Comment: Can you add sample code to question?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay and for the horrible form of the question: what i want and what i realize is only to reproduce the behavior of the extjs dateTrigger present in the extjs datefield. I resolve my problem using an HTML button and in the onClick i open an 'Ext.menu.DatePicker'.